# Prove the inequality $\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{k} \cdot \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+1} \le \frac{9}{8}n^2$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, convexity-inequality

> Prove that for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the inequality $$\sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{k} \cdot \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{k+1} \le \frac{9}{8}n^2$$ holds.

**My work**. I proved this inequality, but my proof is ugly (it is necessary to check by brute force whether the inequality holds for $n=1,2,3,4,5$).

Comment: Have you looked at Riemann sums ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum ) ?

Comment: $\sum_{n=1}^{N} f(n) = \int_{\varepsilon}^{N+1} f(x)d\lfloor x \rfloor, ~ 0<\varepsilon<1$

Comment: The first expression looks like $\approx n^2-(log(n))^2\lt \frac{9n^2}{8}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First problem.

Let $x_k=\frac{k+1}{k}.$

Thus, $x_k\in[1,2]$ for all $k$.

Now, let $$f(x_1,x_2,...x_n)=\sum_{k=1}^nx_k\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{x_k}.$$
Easy to see that $f$ is a convex function of $x_k$ for all $k$.

Thus, by AM-GM $$\max_{x_k\in[1,2]}f=\max_{x_k\in\{1,2\}}f=\max_{i+j=n}(i+2j)\left(i+\frac{j}{2}\right)=$$
$$=\max_{i+j=n}\left((i+j)^2+\frac{1}{2}ij\right)\leq n^2+\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^2=\frac{9}{8}n^2.$$

Comment: I'm very interested in your proof, but unfortunately I do not understand your proof. Please explain this step $$\max_{x_k\in[1,2]}f=\max_{x_k\in\{1,2\}}f=\max_{i+j=n}(i+2j)\left(i+\frac{j}{2}\right)$$ in more detail. Also i don't know what is AM-GM.

Comment: @Witold Convex function gets a maximal value for extreme value of the variable. Draw it! For example if you'll take a parabola $y=x^2$ on $[-1,2]$ so since $y=x^2$ is a convex function $x^2$ gets a maximal value for $x=-1$ or for $x=2$, which gives $\max_{[-1,2]}x^2=\max\{(-1)^2,2^2\}=4.$ In our case it's enough to prove our inequality for $x_k\in\{1,2\}$. AM-GM here it's the following: $ij\leq\left(\frac{i+j}{2}\right)^2.$

Comment: Thank you! I understand what you wrote. But how to prove that the function $f$ is convex?

Comment: @Witold I did not say that $f$ is a convex function. I said that $f$ is a convex function of $x_k$ for all $k$. I see it so. Let $x_k=x$. Thus, $f=(x+A)\left(\frac{1}{x}+B\right)=1+AB+Bx+\frac{A}{x},$ which is a convex function of $x$.

Comment: Very nice proof! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Witold You are welcome! Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

The first inequality is equivalent to
$$(n+H_n)(n+1-H_{n+1})\le\frac98n^2$$
where $H_n$ denotes the $n$th Harmonic number. It's well known that $H_n=\gamma+\ln{(n)}+o(1)$ as $n\to\infty$ so it's clear that the LHS is asymptotic to $n^2+n+o(n)$. In particular, we have that the LHS divided by $n^2$ is decreasing. So we just need to find the ratio of this function and $n^2$ for small $n$ and as the ratio begins to decrease, it will not increase again due to the function's asymptotic behaviour. Using this gives us the much stricter inequality
$$(n+H_n)(n+1-H_{n+1})\le\frac{104273}{100800}n^2$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Equality only occurs when $n=6$ and the ratio is at a maximum.

The second inequality is equivalent to
$$(n^2+2n-H_n)(n^2-2n-3+3H_{n+1})\le\frac98n^4$$
A similar analysis to before gives us the asymptotic $n^4+n^2(2\ln{(n)}+2\gamma-7)+o(n^2)$ for the LHS. Dividing this by $n^4$ gives a decreasing ratio so we again only need to analyse small values of $n$. This gives us the stricter inequality
$$(n^2+2n-H_n)(n^2-2n-3+3H_{n+1})\le\frac{1975}{1944}n^4$$
for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Equality only occurs when $n=3$ in this case.

Comment: You can use $H_n = \ln(n)+\gamma+\frac{c}{2k}$ where $0 < c < 1$.

Comment: @martycohen I see that it's more useful to use $o(1)$ in this case to prevent the problem from becoming overcomplicated.

Comment: Thank you very much!